# IntelliJ: See all changes for a specific "task"

Tags: intellij-idea, jira

IntelliJ has the "task" feature where you can track the context for a Jira task, for example.

Now, I changed several files within this task und committed a few times. After a week, I returned to this project and I'd like to see ***all*** changed files for this task, from the start of the task until where I left of. I cannot find an option to do this, is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

By default creating a new task offers you to create a separate branch for this task. If you did so, all your commits are in that branch.

If you used another branch, I don;t think there is an easy way to do what you want. You could try checking the saved contexts under **Tools - Tasks and Context - Load context**